# Got undefined when I try to reach data from node API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, fetch-api

I tried to use `fetch()` method into `componentDidMount()` method in my react App.

It works on Postman and I got data from URL.

Here is the code in react App:

```
class WorldMap extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
      zoom: 1,
      color: "#39464E",
      test: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      ReactTooltip.rebuild()
    }, 100)

    //get all countries in db
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/country/20', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({test: data.name_fr})
    })
  }

  countryClick(geography){ 
    console.log(test)
  }
}
```

Here is what i got in Postman when I try to retrieve data :

[image]

The problem is that I have undefined in console when I click on country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `json` structure in postman, looks like you need to access `data.name_fr` of the response. Also `fetch` defaults to get and you don't need those extra headers. Your fetch code can be simplified to:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/country/20')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(body => console.log(body.data.name_fr))
```

Comment: Even with this simplification, the console says "undefined". I can't understand !

Comment: what do you get on `console.log(body)`

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong data access. In your `then`, `data` will be the entire resulting object, with `data`, `error`, and `message` properties. If you logged the `data` object entirely before you assigned it to your state, you'd probably have noticed that your assumptions were wrong on what was passed to you. Next time, I suggest debugging with the devtools with breakpoints and/or setting logs to trace where the issue is.

```
.then(data => {
  this.setState({test: data.name_fr})
})
```

should be

```
.then(results => {
  this.setState({test: results.data.name_fr})
})
```

Comment: I tried this, I got an error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name_fr' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Change your fetch to this :

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/country/20', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
  },
})
.then(data => data.json())
.then(jsonData => 
this.setState({test:jsonData.name_fr})
)
```

Comment: I typed exactly what you wrote. I got undefined.

Comment: What do you see when console.log(jsonData) ?